# How to cut off leading digits? C++

Tags: c++, iomanip

How can I cut off the leading digits of a number in order to only display the last two digits, without using the  library. For example:

1923 to 23

2001 to 01

1234 to 34

123 to 23

with only

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're just working with integers I'd suggest just doing mod %100 for simplicity:

```
int num =2341;

cout << num%100;
```

Would display 41.

And if you need a leading zero just do:

```
std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << num%100 << std::endl;
```

Comment: This is much simpler, you got my vote (since his question implies he isn't working with strings, no #include <string>)

Comment: You need to set the ostream width and fill character, else this code does not emit the leading zeros. `std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << 3 << '\n';`

Comment: Thanks Rudi, I thought about that when I was first answering the question, but it slipped my mind to actually put it in - included.

Answer (score 6):

If your numbers are in int form (rather than string form), you should think about using the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operator).

If the numbers are in char[] form, there is an easy solution that involves indexing into the string, like:

```
char *myString = "ABCDE";
int lengthOfMyString = 5;
cout << myString[lengthOfMyString - 3]
     << myString[lengthOfMyString - 5]
     << myString[lengthOfMyString - 4];
//outputs the word CAB
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that was extremely simple. I was definitely over thinking that one.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help.  It would be wonderful if you could please click the check mark in order to officially accept my answer.

Comment: To display only the last two characters (as asked), it's `cout << &myString[lengthOfString - 2]`, where the & operator takes the address of that character, resulting on operator<< streaming a char *, presumed to be ASCIIZ which works nicely here.  For std::string, simply `myString.substr(myString.size() - 2);`  For both, you should know or check that the string has at least 2 characters first.